# Substituir NA na linguagem R

Tags: r

Gostaria de substituir `NA` (*missing*) por uma palavra. Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
structure(list(NOME = c("ABC", "ADD", 
"AFF", "DDD", "RTF", "DRGG"
), TIPO = c("INTERNACAO", "", "CONSULTA", "EXAME", "", "EXAME"
), VALOR = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

#NOME        TIPO  VALOR
#ABC   INTERNACAO     10
#ADD                  20
#AFF     CONSULTA     30
#DDD        EXAME     40
#RTF                  50
#DRGG       EXAME     60
```

Como substituir `NA` pela palavra `TESTE`?

Comment: por favor, melhore se possível a formatação dos dados, indique que função está utilizando e qual seu objetivo com esses dados.

Comment: Tente dar uma olhada nesse vídeo, onde ensinam a substituir valores NA (em inglês): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBVVaCCKeo0

Comment: Olá, ovídeo mostra para todas as colunas. Eu gostaria que substituísse o NA em uma coluna específica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supondo que seu dados estejam num `data frame` chamado `dat`, e que a coluna que você quer substituir os `NA` se chama `TIPO`:

```
dat$TIPO[which(is.na(dat$TIPO))] <- "TESTE"
```

De acordo com seus dados, não vejo `NA` na coluna `TIPO` mas sim elementos vazios. Neste caso, ao invés de `NA`, você usa `" "`.

```
dat$TIPO[which(dat$TIPO == " ")] <- "TESTE"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @BrunoAvila Se resolveu a sua dúvida, seria excelente aceitá-lá.

Comment: Utilizei a expressão dat$TIPO[which(is.na(dat$TIPO))] <- "TESTE" e deu certo. Porém, como faria para substituir o NA pelo conteúdo da coluna ao lado? Exemplo: na linha ADD, o NA seria substituído pelo número 20. Grato

Answer (score 3):

O [`dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) possui uma função chamada [`coalesce`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) que serve exatamente para isso.

No seu caso, poderia usar:

```
library(dplyr)
dat$TIPO <- coalesce(dat$TIPO, "TESTE")
```

Answer (score 1):

A função `case_when` do pacote `dplyr` também faz o que deseja. Antes, note que há uma diferença entre `NA` (*missings*) e `""` (*empty cells*), como citado nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259846/108927).

Primeiro, reproduzir seus dados:

```
df_1 <- structure(list(NOME = c("ABC", "ADD", "AFF", "DDD", "RTF", "DRGG"
), TIPO = c("INTERNACAO", "", "CONSULTA", "EXAME", "", "EXAME"
), VALOR = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

#  NOME       TIPO VALOR
#1  ABC INTERNACAO    10
#2  ADD               20
#3  AFF   CONSULTA    30
#4  DDD      EXAME    40
#5  RTF               50
#6 DRGG      EXAME    60
```

Agora a análise:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(across(TIPO, ~ case_when(. == "" ~ "TESTE", TRUE ~ .)))

#  NOME       TIPO VALOR
#1  ABC INTERNACAO    10
#2  ADD      TESTE    20
#3  AFF   CONSULTA    30
#4  DDD      EXAME    40
#5  RTF      TESTE    50
#6 DRGG      EXAME    60
```

Se existissem `NA`s (*missings*) ao invés de `""` (*empty cells*) o código ficaria assim:

```
df_1 %>% 
  mutate(across(TIPO, ~ case_when(is.na(.) ~ "TESTE", TRUE ~ .)))
```