# Como retirar NA de um dataframe no R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho um `DF` que possui alguns `NA`, como vou utilizá-lo para montar uma tabela, necessitava de trocar os `NA` por " ", para só aparecer o espaço vazio na tabela. Estou utilizando um `mutate_if` para deixar os números com apenas duas casas decimais e trocar de `.` para `,`.

Tentei utilizar o seguinte código, com `mutate` e `replace_na`, mas não deu certo, os `NA` continuam aparecendo.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, format, scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", digits = 2) %>%
    mutate_all(~ replace_na(., NA))
```

Meu `dput`:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("Brasil", "Alimentação no domicílio", 
                           "Arroz", "Feijão-carioca (rajado)", "Farinha de trigo"),
                     b = c(NA, 0.02, 2.71, 9.82, 3.35), c = c(NA, 0.38, 3.69, 10.96, 3.62), 
                     d = c(NA, 0.87, 4.13, 7.28, 3.14), e = c(NA, 1.11, 4.02, 10.09, 3.24), 
                     f = c(NA, 1.13, 4.27, 9.23, 3.43), g = c(NA, NA, 0.15367429760666, 0.0882935186561618, 0.0116253902185224)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Isso te [ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/259767/substituir-na-na-linguagem-r)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seguinte solução consegue fazer o que a pergunta pede.

```
library(tidyverse)

fun <- function(x) {sub("(^.*\\d,\\d\\d)(.*$)", "\\1", sub("\\.", ",", x))}

df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, " "))) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(b:g), fun)
#                         a    b     c    d     e    f    g
#1                   Brasil                                
#2 Alimentação no domicílio 0,02  0,38 0,87  1,11 1,13     
#3                    Arroz 2,71  3,69 4,13  4,02 4,27 0,15
#4  Feijão-carioca (rajado) 9,82 10,96 7,28 10,09 9,23 0,08
#5         Farinha de trigo 3,35  3,62 3,14  3,24 3,43 0,01
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os [ ], que são uma ferramenta de indexação poderosíssima e subestimada, assim:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- ''
```

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente solução!

Comment: Evite o uso de comentários para adradecimentos, fico feliz em notar sua gratidão, mas não precisa, sejamos o mais objetivos possíveis, afinal, é nisso que o SOpt se baseia. Recomendo a leitura do [Manual de Sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas)